# How to install PHP 7.2 on macOS Big Sur using Homebrew?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-7.2

I want to install PHP 7.2 on MacBook Pro M1, macOS Big Sur (11.5.2).

I already read an article ([How To Install a PHP 7.2 on macOS 10.15 Catalina Using Homebrew and PECL](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-install-a-php-7-2-on-macos-10-15-catalina-using-homebrew-and-pecl-ad5b6c9ffb17)), but it doesn't work for me.

I used Homebrew to install PHP 7.2 using this command:

```sh
brew install php@7.2
```

But I've got this error:

```
php@7.2 has been disabled because it is deprecated upstream!
```

Comment: "but he is also use same command" - yes, but not on an M1 and in 2019. Things get deprecated in three years.

Comment: PHP 7.2 reached [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) over a year ago. Brew won't install it for you because it is very out of date and doesn't get security updates. It's dangerous to use and you should upgrade instead of trying to use it.

Comment: I doubt that MacOS will allow you to install [unsupported versions of php](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: but the project i use depending on this verions of PHP how can i solve this matter

Comment: ``brew tap exolnet/homebrew-deprecated`` then ``brew install php@7.2`` should install.

Comment: Your project will probably run in slightly higher version which is still supported. If not, it needs some updates to it, in order to remain current and supportable.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Since PHP 7.2 is not supported anymore, it's got delisted from the **Hombrew** core repository.

You've to find a third-party repository that still contains an older PHP version, such as the `shivammathur/php` repository.

You need to tap the repository like this in your Homebrew:

```sh
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

Then you can install PHP 7.2 like this:

```sh
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.2
```

You can find more information around the above tap and available versions on its GitHub [repository](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php).

Comment: I believe `brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.2` -- not `brew install php@7.2`

Comment: You are right, it's because the `php@7.2` formula still exists on the core repository. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! The one solution I found still working in late 2022.

Answer (score 0):

These worked for me

rm -rf $(brew --repo homebrew/core)

brew tap homebrew/core

brew install php